# Starting AudioKit results in AudioHAL_Client errors 50% of the time

Tags: audiokit

I've been using AudioKit for over 8 months, but recently I've run into a weird issue.

When I start AudioKit, in (roughly) 50% of the cases the audio stops playing after a few seconds and I get a stream of lower-level AudioHAL_Client errors:

```
2019-03-14 17:17:15.567027+0100 TestApp[68164:1626512] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:1399:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: failed to send the final message to the server, Error: 0x10000003
2019-03-14 17:17:16.104180+0100 TestApp[68164:1626365] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ShellPlugIn.cpp:817:HAL_HardwarePlugIn_ObjectHasProperty:  HAL_HardwarePlugIn_ObjectHasProperty: no object
```

or:

```
2019-03-15 08:15:33.756244+0100 macOSDevelopment[47186:2925180] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:1399:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: failed to send the final message to the server, Error: 0x10000003
2019-03-15 08:15:34.290366+0100 macOSDevelopment[47186:2925038] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ShellPlugIn.cpp:817:HAL_HardwarePlugIn_ObjectHasProperty:  HAL_HardwarePlugIn_ObjectHasProperty: no object
2019-03-15 08:15:34.290431+0100 macOSDevelopment[47186:2925038] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ShellPlugIn.cpp:817:HAL_HardwarePlugIn_ObjectHasProperty:  HAL_HardwarePlugIn_ObjectHasProperty: no object
```

It is not related to my specific app, because when I build the AudioKit macOS development app, the same happens. I've also tried it with a clean macOS project.

This is enough to trigger the bug:

```
AudioKit.output = AKMixer()
AudioKit.start()
```

Same happens when I connect an AKOscillator instead of AKMixer.

I've tried to debug this, but I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you using the standard Mac hardware, like the speaker output, or do you by any chance use an external audio module?

Comment: I think I found the problem: after deinstalling LoopBack (https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) everything's back to normal.